# Where is <root-of-android-source-tree>/build/target/product/security

Tags: android

I don't know where to find `<root-of-android-source-tree>/build/target/product/security`
How can I find out ? I want to get file platform.pk8 + platform.x509.pem
I've tried to check in rom android and my phone on the app root explorer, but couldn't find it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These files are not stored on the phone, they are certificates located on the machine that builds the Android system image used on your phone. Each phone vendor signs its system images with its own version of these keys and they are not public.

Comment: I've tried check in system.img in rom but not have anything, Execute me, I don't understand "Android system image" that you say.

Comment: "android system image" = firmware = the ROM your phone is running. For example if you have a Samsung Phone with stock firmware, the firmware is made and signed by Samsung using private Samsung certificates.

Comment: How can I go to `<root-of-android-source-tree>/build/target/product/security` ,I not found in rom, because I want to  generate a certificate:

`./keytool-importkeypair -k google_certificate.keystore -p android -pk8 platform.pk8 -cert  platform.x509.pem -alias platform`

Comment: Are you trying to build a custom ROM? You need to check out the full Android source tree to be able to go to that directory: https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html It contains test keys by default, phone vendors generate their own.

Comment: Yes, I want to build a custom rom, I want to sign certificate rom and app, because my app error "inject permission". I don't know how to?

Comment: Your english is not clear but I think I understand you want to sign an app of yours with a system certificate so that it's allowed to use system permissions ? You can do this, but only if you build a ROM for your phone from scratch. Then you sign your app with the same certificate you used to build your ROM. The link provided above provides the procedure for building ROMs for Nexus devices. You could also build a Cyanogenmod ROM.